# Timezone conflict between PHP and Mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have an issue with the date creation. The php server settings for timezone :
by using the date_default_timezone_get() php function, refers to UTC whereas the MSQL query for  timezone i.e @@system_time_zone is referring to MST. It is  a shared server, so I will not be able to make changes in the my.conf file on the server.

I want the date to be in UTC format, How do I go about making changes on the mysql server so that the Now() function and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns date values wrt  UTC.

Comment: Have a look at this post - it might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right you can try and set a timezone per session from client code

```sql
SET time_zone = timezone;
```

Depending on whether you have timezone info imported or not it may look like

```sql
SET time_zone = 'Etc/UTC';
```

or

```sql
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
```

Further reading:

- [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: Will this affect only the current database connection then? If there are multiple databases on the server I do not want this to affect any other db.

Comment: As stated it will affect only the session in which you connect to your database. It doesn't affect any other sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching date from mysql query using UTC_TIMESTAMP() instead of NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP() will give you date in UTC.